# How do I open a file from TextEdit on MacOSX?

Tags: macos, textedit

How do I create a link in TextEdit on MacOSX that will let me open an external application?

Comment: "External" as in same hard disk or volume?

Comment: Yes, that's not clear. I just meant another application - i.e. not another copy of TextEdit. Nothing to do with hard disk or volume.

Answer (score 3):

Doing **TextField / Edition / Edit Link** (**Add Link** if you've got any text selected)or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, will let you add an *Hyperlink*.

Typing `file://` before the application's file path will give you a *bluish* clickable text, which, on click, will open the file path. Here's how it should look like:

`file:///Applications/NameOfTheApplication.app`

It **won't** open the Application, but will open a new *Finder* window with the item already selected.

Comment: Shame you can't actually open an application but this does help.